# Multiple check boxes will not hold the value of checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am populating values into a data table by using a check box group. You check the box and a value shows up in the table.  However, I cannot get multiple check boxes  to hold their value of 'checked'  and not get multiple values to display in the table.  Below is my code for the check box.  Thanks for the help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // - jQuery SHOW/HIDE functions
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showJobtitles :checkbox').live('click', function() {
            var checkboxVal = $('#showJobtitles :checkbox:checked').val();
            $('.jobTitleCol_' + checkboxVal).toggle();
            $('.jobTitleTD_' + checkboxVal).toggle();
            //$( "p" ).toggle( "slow" );
            //alert(checkboxVal);
            //return this.filter('#showJobtitles, #jobTitleCol_'+checkboxVal+':checkbox').attr("checked", true);
            //$('#showJobtitles :checkbox:checked',true).val();
            //$('.jobTitleTD').toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first use **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showJobtitles').on('click',':checkbox', function() {
  // see from here---------------------------------------------------
  var chkval=[];
  var checkboxVal = $('#showJobtitles :checkbox:checked').find( 
            function(){
            chkval.push($(this).val());
           });

alert(chkval.join(","));
 //------------------------------------------------ 

  $('.jobTitleCol_' + checkboxVal).toggle();
            $('.jobTitleTD_' + checkboxVal).toggle();
            //$( "p" ).toggle( "slow" );
            //alert(checkboxVal);
            //return this.filter('#showJobtitles, #jobTitleCol_'+checkboxVal+':checkbox').attr("checked", true);
            //$('#showJobtitles :checkbox:checked',true).val();
            //$('.jobTitleTD').toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
```